# Show that if both a, b are even integers not both 0, then $(a, b) = 2 (a/2, b/2)$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility, proof-verification

Show that if both a, b are even integers not both 0, then $(a, b) = 2 (a/2, b/2)$.

Hi there, I want to know if the following proof I have is strong enough, or if I'm making false assumptions :|. Thanks :)

Let $d = (a, b), then d = ma + nb$, the least positive linear combination of a, b for integers m, n.

Now since a, b are even, then a = 2k and b = 2l for some integers k and l.

Then $d = ma + nb = 2(m(a/2) + n(a/2)) = 2(a/2, b/2)$ since m, n were chosen to get the least positive linear combination.

I don't think my assumption where $d = ma + nb = 2(m(a/2) + n(a/2)) = 2(a/2, b/2)$ since m, n were chosen to get the least positive linear combination is correct?

Comment: $m,n$ give the least value for $ma+nb$; why should they give the least value for $ma'+nb'$ for some other integers $a',b'$?

Comment: (+1) for showing work. Maybe wrap your equations in dollars signs henceforth...?

Comment: Look at the sixth property [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greatest_common_divisor). Your proof is correct, but you ought to justify certain things (such as vadim123's concern). This isn't hard, but maybe isn't obvious if you don't know some of the more basic properties very well.